# How to rectify TypeError str not defined

Tags: python

We must ask the user how many minutes they have used in a month, and multiply it by 0.10 to get the amount they have spent on minutes.

Code:

```
mins = input("How many minutes have you used this month? ")
minsprice = float(mins)*0.10
print ("You have used",round(mins,2),"GBP worth of minutes this month.")
```

It returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\assessment.py", line 23, in <module>
    print ("You have used",float(round(mins,2)),"GBP worth of minutes this month.")
TypeError: type str doesn't define __round__ method
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a typo. You write `mins`. It should be `minsprice` in last line.

```
    mins = input("How many minutes have you used this month? ")
    minsprice = float(mins)*0.10
    print ("You have used",round(minsprice,2),"GBP worth of minutes this month.")
```

Comment: You have a question? I have an answer.

`print ("You have used %.2f"% round(minsprice,2),"GBP worth of minutes this month.")`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo. You write `mins`. It should be `minsprice` in last line. Thats why the error occurs. Try this

```
mins = input("How many minutes have you used this month? ")
    minsprice = float(mins)*0.10
    print ("You have used",round(minsprice,2),"GBP worth of minutes this month.")
```